# Left speaker/earphones not working

Tags: speakers

Good day to all of you Linux users. This is my first time getting a Linux operating system and I would like to get some help about my left speaker and earphones not working and my speaker is working fine on windows but after I install Ubuntu this is the first problem that occurred.

I am running on a Lenovo-G560 laptop with Ubuntu 21.04 installed

Comment: Welcome to Linux. There isn't enough information here to offer an answer, so could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the brand/model of computer you're using. With this, it may be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: @matigo I have already edited my question

Comment: Have you checked your **Settings** / **Sound** / **Balance** configuration and tried the **Test** function for both left and right speakers?

Comment: @stumblebee yes and I even double check it just to make sure :(

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-January/000276.html https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Please note Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format; ie. 21.04 was the 2021-April release which had 9 months of supported life.  It reached its EOL only hours ago.  You should *release-upgrade* to 21.10; OR if it's a new install you could start again with a *supported* release of Ubuntu  (*you can re-install Ubuntu Desktop releases without touching user files, or needing to re-install manually installed apps (from Ubuntu repositories), just don't format & re-use existing partitions*)   Use a LTS release if you don't wish to *release-upgrade* ever 6-9 months (21.04 + 9 months = 2022.Jan EOL)

Comment: @guiverc ok thank you so much for your answer i will try to update Ubuntu now

Comment: Just FYI as you're new to Ubuntu I gather; the kernel you're currently using is 5.11, so when you *release-upgrade* (or re-install) & switch to Ubuntu 21.10; you'll be using the 5.13 kernel, which will cause all kernel modules to upgrade as well...  (the significance of this is what is commonly known as *drivers* are actually kernel modules.. so you may find it better on 21.10 than it is on 21.04, may also not change - but I'd upgrade first given that's critical & may change things here...)

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not realize 21.04 reached EOL just hours ago, After your upgrade to 21.10, IMHO, I highly recommend sticking with LTS releases from here on out instead of bleeding edge technology. 22.04 LTS will be released in April of this year.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I changed from 2-channel mode to 4-channel in alsamixer. I could solve it by using the left and right arrow keys to access the channel option, then using the up and down arrow keys to change the value to 4 or 6 channels.

You can open alsamixer in Terminal like this:

[image: Open alsamixer using this command in terminal]